# How do add mycss.less in head magento2

Tags: css, magento2

I added to `app\design\frontend\magento\new\Magento_Theme\layout`:

```
<page>
< head>
  < css src = " css / mycss.css " / >
  < / head>
</page>
```

but when I edit the file `mycss.less`, css does not change. What is wrong?

Comment: So you want to add a new css file?

Comment: yes i want add css file last .

Answer (score 1):

To add a css file in your new theme you will need to create a file called `default_head_blocks.xml` which lives in `app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/Magento_Theme/layout/`

In this xml file you can then add your css like so:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles-m.css" />
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
        <css src="css/print.css" media="print" />
    </head>
</page>
```

source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

**EDIT:**

To compile you `less` file after you have made changes from the command line you will need to run `lessc mycss.less` from the command line.

Comment: i made it but not success.

Comment: pub\static\frontend\Magento\new\en_US\css file mycss.css be automatically created. but when i edit mycss.less thi mycss.less not change. you any suggestion. any thanks.

Comment: I just updated my answer hope that helps.

Comment: i'm try fix Stores-> Advanced->Developper-> Font-end Development workflow -> workflow type -> client side less compilation. is success.